# Sistema de creditos - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugin, pagamento-online

Alguém conhece um plugin ou script que funcione como créditos/pontos?

Ou seja para fazer um download irá usar X créditos, e o utilizador pode comprar via paypal ou algo desse género.

**Plugins Vistos:**

- Easy Digital Downloads
- wpdeposit
- User Credits for WordPress

Answer (score 2):

Pesquisei um bocado para responder, e para mim a melhor opção que encontrei é um plugin chamado **[User Credits](http://codecanyon.net/item/user-credits-for-wordpress/783664)**. Ele atende aos requisitos que você pede, e alguns outros mais. Depende da configuração que você efetuar! Note que o plugin vem primariamente integrado com o Paypal, mas preparado para integrar com outras soluções.

Comment: Desde já obrigada pela rápida resposta =) Esse tinha visto e [este](http://codecanyon.net/item/wpdeposit/500402) mas a pergunta foi para perceber até que ponto já foi usado pelos utilizadores e se é funcional. Plugins gratuitos não efectuam todos estes pormenores de forma correta pelo que pesquisei.

Comment: @3L3KTRA, por isso é importante que você mencione *na pergunta* os resultados da sua pesquisa inicial. Isso evita que alguém recomende uma solução que você já conhece.

Comment: @brasofilo tens toda a razão, mas infelizmente fiz a pesquisa num computador que já foi à vida e não tinha os links, nem os nomes. Quando me indicam algum plugin eu vou ver e respondo que já tinha visto o que me ajuda pois agora já estão salvos =)

Answer (score 2):

Não tenho certeza se o resultado desejado pode ser alcançado pois neste caso específico isso requer comprar, instalar e testar, mas desconfio que sim. O plugin [**Easy Digital Downloads**](https://easydigitaldownloads.com) (gratuito) tem uma variedade enorme de Add-ons (gratuitos e premium), e um deles é [**Points and Rewards**](https://easydigitaldownloads.com/extensions/points-rewards/) ($59):

> Extension for building a “store credit” type system. Want to rewards customers for helping out in your support forums or for reporting a bug? Simply give them some points that can be redeemed on future purchases.

A autor de EDD, [Pippin Williamson](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/2418/pippin), é um *leading developer* na comunidade WordPress. A qualidade de seu código é impecável, sendo muito fácil extender sua funcionalidade através de *hooks* ou criando suas próprias extensões para o EDD.

Comment: Já tinha visto esse plugin, realmente é o que facilita mais o processo...no entanto não sei até que ponto será fácil todo o processo inicial. Inserir downloads com diferentes créditos, e o processo de compra via cartão de crédito, paypal (os mais usados). É uma questão de testar e testar =)